# AzureAD for Android throws ADALError.AUTH_REFRESH_FAILED_PROMPT_NOT_ALLOWED

Tags: android, office365, adal, azure-active-directory

I have an app in which user authentificates in Office365 with [AzureAD library for Android](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-android).

It works well, users can authentificate and work with the app. Unfortunately, after a while they start hitthing **`AuthenticationException`** with  **`ADALError.AUTH_REFRESH_FAILED_PROMPT_NOT_ALLOWED`** as an error code.

I checked the [source code](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-android/blob/662c2a8c49304d09200ed7f2b3fb7c76e3475ae5/src/src/com/microsoft/aad/adal/AuthenticationContext.java) of AzurelAD. The only place, which is throughing this issue is `acquireTokenAfterValidation()` method:

```
private AuthenticationResult acquireTokenAfterValidation(CallbackHandler callbackHandle,
        final IWindowComponent activity, final boolean useDialog,
        final AuthenticationRequest request) {
    Logger.v(TAG, "Token request started");

    // BROKER flow intercepts here
    // cache and refresh call happens through the authenticator service
    if (mBrokerProxy.canSwitchToBroker()
            && mBrokerProxy.verifyUser(request.getLoginHint(),
                    request.getUserId())) {
        .......
        Logger.v(TAG, "Token is not returned from backgroud call");
        if (!request.isSilent() && callbackHandle.callback != null && activity != null) {
            ....
        } else {
            // User does not want to launch activity
            String msg = "Prompt is not allowed and failed to get token:";
            Logger.e(TAG, msg, "", ADALError.AUTH_REFRESH_FAILED_PROMPT_NOT_ALLOWED);
            callbackHandle.onError(new AuthenticationException(
                    ADALError.AUTH_REFRESH_FAILED_PROMPT_NOT_ALLOWED, msg));
        }

        // It will start activity if callback is provided. Return null here.
        return null;
    } else {
        return localFlow(callbackHandle, activity, useDialog, request);
    }
}
```

**My source code:**

```
authenticator.getAccessTokenSilentSync(getMailService());

public class Authenticator {
    ..............
    public String getAccessTokenSilentSync(ServiceInfo serviceInfo) {
        throwIfNotInitialized();
        return getAuthenticationResultSilentSync(serviceInfo).getAccessToken();
    }

    private AuthenticationResult getAuthenticationResultSilentSync(ServiceInfo serviceInfo) {
        try {
            return authenticationContext.acquireTokenSilentSync(
                    serviceInfo.ServiceResourceId,
                    Client.ID,
                    userIdentity.getAdUserId());
        } catch (AuthenticationException ex) {
            // HERE THE EXCEPTION IS HANDLED.
        }
    }
    ..............
}
```

Stacktrace I'm getting:

> ```
>     <package name>.data_access.error_handler.AuthenticationExceptionWithServiceInfo: Refresh token is failed and prompt is not allowed
>     at com.microsoft.aad.adal.AuthenticationContext.localFlow(AuthenticationContext.java:1294)
>     at com.microsoft.aad.adal.AuthenticationContext.acquireTokenAfterValidation(AuthenticationContext.java:1229)
>     at com.microsoft.aad.adal.AuthenticationContext.acquireTokenLocalCall(AuthenticationContext.java:1123)
>     at com.microsoft.aad.adal.AuthenticationContext.refreshToken(AuthenticationContext.java:1609)
>     at com.microsoft.aad.adal.AuthenticationContext.localFlow(AuthenticationContext.java:1261)
>     at com.microsoft.aad.adal.AuthenticationContext.acquireTokenAfterValidation(AuthenticationContext.java:1229)
>     at com.microsoft.aad.adal.AuthenticationContext.acquireTokenLocalCall(AuthenticationContext.java:1123)
>     at com.microsoft.aad.adal.AuthenticationContext.refreshToken(AuthenticationContext.java:1609)
>     at com.microsoft.aad.adal.AuthenticationContext.localFlow(AuthenticationContext.java:1261)
>     at com.microsoft.aad.adal.AuthenticationContext.acquireTokenAfterValidation(AuthenticationContext.java:1229)
>     at com.microsoft.aad.adal.AuthenticationContext.acquireTokenLocalCall(AuthenticationContext.java:1123)
>     at com.microsoft.aad.adal.AuthenticationContext.access$600(AuthenticationContext.java:58)
>     at com.microsoft.aad.adal.AuthenticationContext$4.call(AuthenticationContext.java:1072)
>     at com.microsoft.aad.adal.AuthenticationContext$4.call(AuthenticationContext.java:1067)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
> ```

Version of AzureAD library I'm using: 1.1.7 (to prevent blaming too old version - I've checked the changelist since from 1.1.7 to 1.1.11 and haven't found anything related to question)

**Problem:** Right now, I'm treating this error, as a signal to through the user to the login screen. In my opinion, it leads to a poor experience for the user. The fact that it happens ***very*** often and affects many users make it even worse.

**Question:** Is there anything I can do different to avoid this `AuthenticationException` or workaround it somehow (i.e. avoid user enters credentials once again).

Comment: @iambmelton I'm handling promt by myself in code.  So I'm wondering if once I got the exception is it too late to do any attempts to explicitly refresh token or there's any workarounds for it? Regarding if `acquireTokenSilentSync()` is a right method. Well. That's something I want to figure out. For some time (weeks?) it works fine. (I'm doing this call to get token for every backend query). Then it "expires". My gut feeling - it expires too soon.

Comment: @iambmelton OK, I got it: so it's sort of expected behavior, that after some time - 2 weeks - users has been throwing to the login screen once again and there's no way to prevent it. That's sad, but still - good to know! (Regarding silent/non-silect - yep, I do silent in order to handle the auth flow manually in order to have nice view for entering email (like in OneDrive, for example)).  Btw, if you convert your comments into the answer - I can accept it

Comment: Ok! Posted below, I'll clean out the comments here to remove duplicated info :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you verified that `AuthenticationContext.acquireTokenSilentSync()` is truly the method that you wish to invoke?

The docs indicate that this method will explicitly not show a prompt. From the docs:

```
This is sync function. It will first look at the cache and automatically checks for the token expiration. Additionally, if no suitable access token is found in the cache, but refresh token is available, the function will use the refresh token automatically. This method will not show UI for the user. If prompt is needed, the method will return an exception.
```

The refresh token you are issued should last two weeks per this [AAD book](http://bit.ly/1Z6sofq). After the refresh token expires users are expected to reauthenticate. Can you inspect net traffic with Fiddler or Charles and inspect the expiry of the tokens? If you can verify that the tokens are failing to refresh before their expiry it may indicate a bug in the AD library.

To clarify the difference in methods on `AuthenticationContext` - there are two categories of methods: "silent" methods (which will not present a dialog to user in the event that they need to reauthenticate), and non-silent. Non-silent methods will, in the event of requiring reauthentication (or consent) from the user, start a new Activity containing the AAD login. At that point the authentication flow is restarted.

Additionally, if you make changes to your application's registration in Azure such as adding new permission scopes your users will be required to re-grant consent for the application to continue to handle their data.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you need to refresh your token and implement this in your code so the user won't be prompt to login every time the access token is expired. please check out how to implement refresh token here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn645538.aspx

Hope this helps.